# jquery plugin that scrolls a div from one side of the window to the other

Tags: jquery, animation

I want a div (i will use some image inside it) to scroll from left or right of window to opposite side.

I tried code like this:

```
$('#fly').animate({left: $(window).width()+'px'}, 2000, 'linear'); //initial position is left
```

But it scrolls too fast.

Any jquery plugin that do what i want ?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just increase the duration?

```
$('#fly').animate(
    {left: $(window).width()+'px',
    }, 8000, 'linear');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Steve_Wellens/ejFhK/)

Comment: thanku. but when window is resized, speed varies. So 'duration' and '$(window).width()' is related. Any equations for that? I will try to test `speed = distance / time` for this.

Answer (score 0):

scrollTo http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo